# create a loop and paste

Tags: r, loops, paste

I am having a problem with a loop.
I have a data frame:

```
Transcript=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2)
Exon=rep(c(1:4,1:5))
S=c("aaa","ttt","ccc","ggg","ata","tat","cgc","gcg","bbb")
E=c("AAA","TTT","CCC","GGG","ATA","TAT","CGC","GCG","BBB")
DF=data.frame(Transcript, Exon, S, E)
DF
s=split( DF , DF$Transcript,)
```

I want to subset the dataframe by Transcript and paste column E with S together to give all possible combinations in each transcript. For example, for Transcript 1, I want to return:

> AAAaaa,AAAttt,AAAccc,AAAggg,TTTaaa,TTTttt,TTTccc,TTTggg,CCCaaa,CCCttt,CCCccc,CCCggg,GGGaaa,GGGttt,GGGccc,GGGggg.

I have tried the following loop, but it only returns the `AAAaaa` `AAAttt` `AAAccc` `AAAggg`:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(s[[1]])){p=paste(s[[1]][1,4],s[[1]][1:i,3],sep="")}
```

How to I create this loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
lapply(s, function(df) apply(expand.grid(df$E, df$S),1,paste0,collapse=""))
```

Or, as proposed by @akrun,

```
lapply(s, function(df) do.call(paste0, expand.grid(df$E, df$S)))
```

Comment: Good use of expand.grid!

Comment: You could also do `lapply(s, function(df) do.call(paste0, expand.grid(df$E, df$S)))`

Answer (score 1):

You could try `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[,Reduce(paste0,CJ(E, S)), by=Transcript]
```

#### data

```
DF <- data.frame(Transcript, Exon, S, E)
```